# Compare one field between two rows in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I have a small table which contains group memberships to which I am struggling to find a query.

```
   uid     groupid     userid
    1         2          5
    2         2          6
    3         1          2
    4         3          8
    5         4          7
```

I was wondering if it is possible to return TRUE if two given user IDs where in the same group?

Comment: So `groupid` 2 is what you want to identify?

Comment: @HartCO It sounds more like he wants to accept two `UserId` params, and return 1 or 0 depending on if those two ID's have the same `GroupId`

Comment: yes, I want to identify whether `groupid` is the same for 2 given `userid`

Comment: Is `userid UNIQUE NOT NULL` and `groupid NOT NULL` in your table, like the sample data seems to suggest? As *always*, a table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) would clarify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gets all groups that have two given members:

```
select groupid
from table t
where userid in ($userid1, $userid2)
group by groupid
having count(distinct userid) = 2;
```

You can turn this into a boolean if you like:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then true else false end)
from (select groupid
      from table t
      where userid in ($userid1, $userid2)
      group by groupid
      having count(distinct userid) = 2
     ) g;
```

Comment: Thank you this has also worked great and gave me the correct result. I will experiment with both answers and see which one fits better on a larger scale.

Comment: How would I get around it passing out false if you feed it 2 same IDs?

Comment: @Arturski . . . You would need logic to change the 2 to a 1 . . . perhaps `having count(distinct userid) = (case when @userid1 = $userid2 then 1 else 2 end)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT groupid, CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct userid) > 1 THEN "TRUE" ELSE "FALSE" END
FROM my_table
WHERE userid IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY groupid
```

*Note the x and y should be replaced with the given userids*

**TRUE:**

```
SELECT groupid, CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct userid) > 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
FROM my_table
WHERE userid IN (5,6)
GROUP BY groupid
```

**FALSE:**

```
SELECT groupid, CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct userid) > 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
FROM my_table
WHERE userid IN (5,2)
GROUP BY groupid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3f156/1

Comment: The fiddle is for MySQL, but the question is for Postgres, where double-quotes are for identifiers (as per SQL standard) and your syntax is invalid.

Comment: Sorry by default I'm in Mysql modus :(, updated the everything to Postgres

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm... i tested it on gpadmin 3 and the TRUE and FALSE did not require any double quotes or apostrophes. If a user is a member of more than 1 group it returns 2 rows, one as false and one as true. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### `UNIQUE userid`

Each user can only have at most one entry (like the question seems to ask).

```
SELECT (SELECT groupid FROM tbl WHERE userid = 5)
     = (SELECT groupid FROM tbl WHERE userid = 6);
```

Assuming `userid`is `UNIQUE`.
Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` *exactly* like requested.
- or `NULL` if a `userid` is not found or `groupid` is NULL.

### `UNIQUE (userid, groupid)`

Each user can only have multiple entries (as clarified in the comment):

Share all groups?

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM      (SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 5) a
   FULL JOIN (SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 6) b USING (groupid)
   WHERE a.groupid IS NULL OR
         b.groupid IS NULL
   ) AS share_all;
```

Share at least one group?

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 8
   INTERSECT
   SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 9
   ) AS share_min_one;
```

Or

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM  (SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 5) a
  JOIN  (SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 6) b USING (groupid)
  ) AS share_min_one;
```

Share exactly one group?

```
SELECT count(*) = 1 AS share_exactly_one
FROM  (SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 5) a
JOIN  (SELECT groupid FROM tbl2 WHERE userid = 6) b USING (groupid);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51887/6) with better test data.

All of these queries are fast with an index on `userid`. Faster with a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(userid, groupid)` in Postgres 9.2+.

Ultimately this is a case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division). Here's an arsenal of query techniques:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

Comment: This query works but only in cases where users cannot be part of more than one group. My fault for not clarifying this at the start.

Comment: @Arturski: The question asks `if two given user IDs where in the same group`. Singular indicates *one* group, the dummy data supports that and you did not answer my RFC at first. Now, if a single user can be in multiple groups, you need to clarify more: Is `(groupid, userid)` unique? Do you want users that share all groups, exactly one group (like your question still indicates) or at least one group? That's really a different question. I added some more answers.